# how to set a gradient color for each row in datagridview after data binding

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, datagridview

I want to set a gradient color for each row in datagridview after data binding(I mean in DataBoundCompleted event)

I see this Articles but all of them are for selecting a row.I want set gradient for each rows.

[DataGridView, add unique gradient to each Row](http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/75039/DataGridView-add-unique-gradient-to-each-Row.aspx#answer1)

[How to: Customize the Appearance of Rows in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85kxk29c.aspx)

thanks

Answer (score 2):

The second example you link to is exactly the one you need. The [DataGridView.RowPrePaint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowprepaint.aspx) event is fired for every row within the grid.

The example on the documentation page for this event only custom-renders the selected row, because it includes the following check.

```
// Determine whether the cell should be painted
// with the custom selection background.
if ((e.State & DataGridViewElementStates.Selected) ==
            DataGridViewElementStates.Selected)
```

Remove this check an you will see every row has a custom background.

Comment: I remove that code but the gradient color does not apply to rows.I don't know why.It seems default style override this style

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this well help someone who lands here after a Google search, I based this on some vb code I found in another forum:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

namespace CPS
{
    class gradientGrid : DataGridView
    {

        protected override void PaintBackground(System.Drawing.Graphics graphics, System.Drawing.Rectangle clipBounds, System.Drawing.Rectangle gridBounds)
        {
            base.PaintBackground(graphics, clipBounds, gridBounds);

            System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush b = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(clipBounds, Color.CadetBlue, Color.AntiqueWhite, System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientMode.Horizontal);
            graphics.FillRectangle(b, clipBounds);
        }
    }
}
```

once you have built this as a seperate class it shows up in your (VS2010) toolbox and you drop it on your form ...

This code works for the entire datagrid view so to do it for each row, you can use the **RowPrePaint** event...